# Azure Node.js Internal Server Error from index.js file

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-web-app-service

I have a Node.js app working locally, however I have spent quite a while trying to figure out how to deploy it on Azure through countless tutorials and official guides. However, I keep on receiving the following error 
"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.", which I believe is caused by my index.js file. My app only consists of an index.js, packagage.json, and a main.html file.

Could you take a look at my index.js and package.json file below to see 
if you could spot any errors? I appreciate your help.

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.render('main', function(err, html) {
console.log(html)
});


var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
server.listen(port);
console.log("Server running at http://localhost:%d", port);
```

package.json

```
{
"name": "myLocalProj",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "node index.js"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"ejs": "^2.6.1",
"express": "^4.16.3",
"path": "^0.12.7"
}
}
```

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't post complete code snippet in the question, so I use a template for displaying main.html when visit the Azure web root url.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

// This method only prints main.html in console
app.render('main', function(err, html) {
    console.log(html);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('main');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
app.listen(port);
console.log("Server running at http://localhost:%d", port);
```

To make this node app work on Azure(IIS), we need a web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^index.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So folder structure should be like this.

[image]

You don't mention how you deploy the code, I just use Zip Deploy to test.

Create a zip file with all content(including node_modules), go to `https://yourwebappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/ZipDeploy` and drag it to browser.

Then the node app should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, this worked perfectly. The trick was the web.config file.